# Why was a question about SoundCloud moved to Web Applications?

Tags: support, migration

Why was [a question asking if there was a stand-alone player for SoundCloud](https://superuser.com/questions/459998) moved to *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour)*?

The question has nothing to do with web applications; it's asking about if desktop software exists.

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, that should not have been migrated to *Web Applications*. I've cleared the migration history.

Answer (score 0):

The question is about desktop software, so it to me, it appropriately belongs in software recommendations and not superuser.

Comment: SR didn't exist then, and the question is too old for migration. This is the peril of answering a *two year old* meta question